# JCarousellite not working in IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, jcarousel

I have a user who's having issues running the JCarousellite plug-in in IE8. Not just on my own site, but also on the [jcarousellite homepage](http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/). It runs fine on my own machine and all his IE Security settings/levels are the same as my own (Secruity is at "Medium-High" and Privacy at "Medium"). JQuery also seems to be working for him as other aspects controlled by jquery on the site are functioning correctly.

I use Firefox normally, so am not aware of every feature IE8 offers, but am thinking he has some setting/option set incorrectly.

Anyone experienced something similar or have any suggestions for settings I could look at changing? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This probably won't help as it doesn't address the 'same browser' issue, but someone else might wind up here like I did trying to solve a similar problem:

The image width **and** height *must* be specified for IE7/8 to render the image.

It was difficult for me to track down as I develop on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Well this plugin hasn't been updated in a long time. Last official update is from what 2007? The last officially mentioned jQuery version supported is 1.2.x. And if you check the posts to this blog entry: [jCarousel Lite – A jQuery plugin](http://www.gmarwaha.com/blog/2007/08/09/jcarousel-lite-a-jquery-plugin/) you will see plenty of unfixed bug reports. The same for the issue tracker on the jQuery Plugin pages.

About browser support the plugin pages states

> Tested on Internet Explorer 6 and 7,
>   Firefox 2, Opera 9.20, Safari 3.0.1
>   for Windows.

Essentially this seems to be an unsupported plugin for a long time now with a more then just a few bugs.

Better drop it and use one of the other more up-to-date and better supported carousel/slideshow plugins out there. There are literally hundreds of them around

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, the odd thing is that it works fine on IE8 for me and plenty of other users. The website I work for gets over 1 million unique users a month and no one else has reported an issue with the carousel, hence was hoping some one might've experienced something similar.

Comment: Hmm.. if I remember to do so. I will check the jcarousellite homepage next time I have an IE8 available. And play with the settings too. Does your user experience any other js related problems? btw. it would help if you could detail what issues he has? Does it not work at all?

Comment: Great, thanks alot. I really appreciate it.

The user doesn't seem to have had any other js issues. We use jquery on the site and it works for him elsewhere. When he clicks on our carousel, simply nothing happens. We use the carousel in 2 places and neither work for him, nor does the one on the jcarousellite homepage. He says he has the same IE8 security settings as myself, but without access to his machine I can't tell for certain. I've also tried changing IE8 settings on my machine to get the carousel to 'not work' but have had no success.